Troubleshooting Django Logout Error: Despite Correct Implementation, Logout Button Still Generates Error
I get this error every time I press the logout button, which is weird because I did all the right steps and still have the same result.
The error
Method Not Allowed: /accounts/logout/
[03/Apr/2024 02:37:45] "GET /accounts/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
forms.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django import forms

attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}

class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
     def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
         super(UserLoginForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

     username = forms.CharField(
         label='Username',
         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs)
    )
     password = forms.CharField(
         label='Password',
         widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=attrs)
    )



accounts/urls.py
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from django.urls import path,include

from accounts.forms import UserLoginForm    
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(authentication_form=UserLoginForm),name='login'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]

settings.py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',

]
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/login'

project/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('__debug__/',include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('', include('projects.urls')),

]

#logout.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}
<form method="post"  action="{% url 'logout' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-header">
            Log Out
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Are You Sure You Want To Log Out Of YOur Account? {{ user.username|title}} </h5>
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="logout">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}

#header.html
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-danger bg-gradient p-3">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'Project_list' %}">
      <img src="{% static 'media/logo.svg' %}" alt="Forjects Logo"
           width="50" height="50"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'Project_list' %}">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'Project_create' %}">Create Project</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0 me-3 ">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Hello {{ user.username|title }} Welcome Back
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form method="GET" action="{% url 'Project_list' %}" class="d-flex">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
        </div>
      </form>
      {% else %}
      <a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="{% url 'login' %}">{% trans 'Login' %}</a>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

I try to log out, but I can't. I've tried everything and asked a few people I know and still can't fix it.

You must have some other page template that is doing a GET, not a POST, on the logout url.

I have implemented the GET method for the search field in the navbar and also i have a link to logout page in the same navbar

<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a> That link is the reason.  Plain links are GET requests, but the logout view requires a POST request.

What steps do you recommend I take to prevent encountering this error in the future?

Always present the logout url as a POST action, not a GET action.  Generally this will mean you can't use a plain link, you must use a form button (as you are already doing on the logout.html template).  There may be some CSS trickery to style a button so that it looks like a regular link.
